# Running xlwt module in Abaqus

Tags: python, importerror, xlwt

Windows Machine, Python 2.4:

When I run my script in Abaqus' "Run Script...", I get an ImportError saying that xlwt module does not exist. The same script runs perfectly well in my Eclipse IDE or Python IDE. I made sure that I gave the right path to the Python Library.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Further, Abaqus also gives "SystemError: raw_input() may not be called from Abaqus/CAE CLI" when programs that contain raw_input() are run in it. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think raw_input command is just not supported within CAE environment.

You can use getInput() or getInputs() instead.